# How to create xml output for a junit test suite

Tags: xml, junit, suite

I was wondering how I can create an `XML` file for a `Junit` suite.

At the moment I have a custom runner which extends `BlockJUnit4ClassRunner` and generates `XML` each test class with information such as which class was used, which method, as well as some information specific to a given set of classes (which engine was used) etc.

Now I need to do it for the entire suite rather than for each test class. So my question is, is my best option to extend Suite and implement my logic there or is there a better way?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of writing a custom runner, you want a custom `RunListener`.